# Math.Sinh() return different value in c#

Tags: c#

I have this Code in my program :

```
Math.Sinh(myvalue).ToString()
```

Above Code returns `Infinity` in windows 8 and return `∞` in windows 10 .

why it return two diffrent values ?

Comment: The values are the same `double.PositiveInfinity`. Only the string representation changed to the shiny `∞`.

Comment: they should be same , because i use this to encrypt data , this result in my key to encryption . how can I do this ?

Comment: It's going to be very difficult to encrypt data when the result is infinity, no matter what the visual representation is!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value of `Math.Sinh(myvalue)` is still the same `double.PositiveInfinity`. I assume that the resource files containing the string representation for the special double values have been changed in Windows 10 so they now return that infinity symbol `∞`.

If you want to keep your code the old way (which in fact is not a good idea to depend on culture-specific string representations), you may consider something like this:

```
double sinh = Math.Sinh(myvalue);
string v = double.IsInfinity(myvalue) ? "Infinity" : myvalue.ToString();
```

or simply check if the return value of `ToString()` is `∞` and change it accordingly.

But remember that there are some more special double values you may have to check.